# ts-node-dev: no script to run provided

Tags: node.js, typescript

My NodeJs project have an error message:

> dev_api | yarn run v1.15.2
> dev_api | warning package.json: No license field
> dev_api | $ set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --inspect --transpileOnly ./src/index.ts
> dev_api | ts-node-dev: no script to run provided
> dev_api | Usage: ts-node-dev [options] script [arguments]
> dev_api | 
> dev_api | error Command failed with exit code 1.
> dev_api | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

My `package.json`:

```
{
   "name": "API_CLIENT_BANK",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/jest": "^24.0.20",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "@sentry/node": "5.7.1",
      "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
      "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.1",
      "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
      "@types/helmet": "^0.0.44",
      "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.5",
      "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
      "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^3.0.2",
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
      "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
      "class-validator": "^0.10.2",
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "express": "^4.15.4",
      "helmet": "^3.21.2",
      "jest": "^24.9.0",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "morgan": "^1.9.1",
      "mysql": "^2.17.1",
      "prettier": "^1.18.2",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "sqlite3": "^4.0.3",
      "supertest": "^4.0.2",
      "swagger-jsdoc": "^3.4.0",
      "swagger-stats": "^0.95.11",
      "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.43",
      "tsc-watch": "^4.1.0",
      "tslint": "^5.20.0",
      "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
      "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
      "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
      "typeorm": "0.2.20"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "tsc": "tsc",
      "start": "set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --inspect --transpileOnly ./src/index.ts",
      "prod": "tsc && node ./build/index.js",
      "schema:drop": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js schema:drop",
      "schema:sync": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js schema:sync",
      "migration:run": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run",
      "test": "jest --maxWorkers=1 --verbose=true",
      "migration:start": "yarn schema:drop && yarn schema:sync && yarn migration:run"
   }
}
```

The error say **ts-node-dev: no script to run provided**, but I gave it:
`set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --inspect --transpileOnly ./src/index.ts`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That `no script to run provided` error is the slightly unhelpful way that `ts-node-dev`'s behaves if it doesn't recognize an option. (This is true as far as v1.1.6, at any rate.)

The problem here is that it doesn't understand the `--transpileOnly` option. Possibly older versions did, because you see a few examples around the web with that option. But now you need to write `--transpile-only`.

You'd think it would say something like "Unrecognized option: --transpileOnly", but no.

(The answer from Emefile Francis Waje does include this change, but it's easily missed, because it also proposes two more changes: making `ts-node-dev` a dev dependency, and using `npx`. So when I first read that answer, I totally missed the change from `--transpileOnly` to `--transpile-only` because I was focusing on the other two changes. So I'm calling this detail out here in a separate answer because it's the root cause of the error that the question mentions.)

Answer (score 4):

Try to run
`npm i ts-node-dev --save-dev`,
and modify your script to
`npx ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only --debug ./src/index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following options -

Dev dependencies :

```
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
"typescript": "^5.0.4"
```

and script in package.json to start :

```
"start":"ts-node-dev --respawn ./index.ts",
```

It works for me.